# foreign language is not supporting by mailing service and text messages using java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-mail

I'm getting the ???? for sender name , ics attachment and for text message. 
For mailing i used

```
MailService mailService   = MailServiceFactory.getMailService();
MailService.Message message   = new MailService.Message();
String senderName             = appInfo.getEmailInfo().getSenderName()!=null;
senderName                    = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(senderName);
```

using this its working fine. When I'm doing with multipart its not working

```
Multipart multipart          = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
message.setSubject(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(subject));
message.setSentDate(new Date());
MimeBodyPart messagePart     = new MimeBodyPart();
messagePart.setContent(messageContent, mailType +"; charset=utf-8");
```

for attachment

```
MimeBodyPart attachmentPart  = new MimeBodyPart();
attachmentPart.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=utf-8");
attachmentPart.setText(attachment);
```

For text message I have used

```
String customerAddress        = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(customerContact.getAddress());
```

Can anyone help me.

Comment: Are you actually using UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: I'm using UTF-8 encoding

Comment: I'm taking the language values through the input tag, before storing the value I'm doing htmlEscape() to those and storing the values.now I'm converting those to StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml() then I included content-type to utf-8,If I'm wrong with something, can you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to convert sender and subject in HTML. Set them as strings.

Comment: Try to remove HTML escape when you take an input.

Answer (score 0):

Pick a string that's not working correctly.  Print out the original value using this:

```
private static void printString(String s) {
    System.out.printf("String: %s%n");
    for (char c : s.toCharArray())
        System.out.printf("%4x %c%n", (int)c, c);
}
```

Then print out the converted value using the same method.  Post the results.  Then we can see what's going wrong.  The string needs to have the proper Unicode characters, not html escapes, not UTF-8 bytes.  Once the string has the proper Unicode characters, you can use it with mimeMessage.setSubject(subj, "utf-8") and new InternetAddress(address, personal, "utf-8").

Comment: I have a function for htmlEscape,I that I'm having for each html Entity a Unicode for that, for example for this letter ä equivalent is  &auml;,I'm directly storing that value in Datastore.When I decode with htmlDecode(); I'm getting the value in front-end level.but now the problem comes for java mailing service and in SMS service. I don't have any clue who to work on it. please help me

Comment: I'm trying to help you, but you didn't do what I said above.  Does htmlDecode convert &auml; to ä?  Do you get the correct Unicode value for that character using the method above?